# Get data(values) from RasterLayer arcgis js

Tags: raster, layer, arcgis-js-api

I have mapserver which contains tif files (raster layer).This files contains temperature data . I want to know how to get data from this raster layer. I look a lot of arcgis js api samples ,but none of them show how to read data from raster layer.

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS JS API support WCS (Web Coverage Service), OGC standard, which is supported by every map server including MapServer.

In that way, you will use a `WCSLayer`, wich has several properties and methods to handle information of bands an pixels.

[ArcGIS JS API - WCSLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-WCSLayer.html)

[MapServer - WCS](https://www.mapserver.org/ogc/wcs_server.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but i found the solution. I used @arcgis/core/rest/identify for reading the pixel data. I will post an example

Answer (score 0):

```
      import * as identify from "@arcgis/core/rest/identify";
      .
      .
      .
        return identify
            .identify(url, params)
            .then(function (response) {
                var results = response.results;
               
                results.map((result, index) => {
...
}
```

This was solution for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).